# C#: File.Move I/O method works but then throws exception?

Tags: c#, io

I have a windows service, that in a given part of the code does something as the following:

Moves a given txt file `someFile.txt` from a given folder `pending` to a `complete` folder.
The weird part is that it does work: the file is moved to the `complete` folder **but** then the program throw the exception `Could not find file '\\someServer\Pending\someFile.txt'.`

c#

```
//values:
//filePath: \\someServer\Pending\someFile.txt
//completeDirectory: \\someServer\Complete
//fileName: someFile.txt

//some other code...

try
{
    File.Move(filePath, Path.Combine(completeDirectory, fileName));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //Could not find file '\\someServer\Pending\someFile.txt'.
}
```

Does anyone know what could be happening here? thanks

Comment: Are you by any chance calling this twice?

Comment: Hi @tkausl  ! this windows service is scheduled and happens every minute, so can be possible, but as far as I understand, should not be the problem. I was able to reproduce this locally and right after the execution of the File.Move method the file gets moved, and then throws the exception